# python vs source code string cannot contain null bytes

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

**the source code is:**

```
import numpy
import cv2

cap=cv2.videoCapture(0)
while true :
    ret,frame=cap.read()
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('fram',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1)&0xFF==ord('q'):
        break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**the error is:  source code string cannot contain null bytes .
referece to import cv2.
what is the solution?**

Answer (score 2):

Somehow an invisible null byte has found its way into your source code.

One easy way to get rid of it is to paste your code back into the editor from e.g. this question – the null byte will probably not have survived the copy-paste.

Also make sure your editor saves files in the UTF-8 encoding, not e.g. UTF-16 (which will contain null bytes).

Comment: Another solution is to search `\x00` in `print(repr(open('source_code.py').read()))`.

Comment: how can i make sure that my editor saves files in the UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: @halamourad That will depend on which editor you are using, and is a tech support question that should be answered by [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) first.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
import numpy
import cv2
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True :
    ret,frame=cap.read()
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('fram',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1)&0xFF==ord('q'):
        break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: the same problem