# What is Python: ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Tags: python

Why my python just throw an error call:

```
code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 239, in _get_code_from_file
code = compile(f.read(), fname, 'exec')
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

It was fine yesterday and it just have problem today.

It was never happened before and I don't know What is **null bytes**

Other people have this problem are all because using UTF-16 etc. but I'm really using UTF-8
and it really made me headache.

My IDE is VSCode and I'm using UTF-8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58656385/python-vs-source-code-string-cannot-contain-null-bytes

Comment: @balu It's not same problem because I'm not using OpenCV or numpy

Comment: irrespective of OpenCV or NumPy check this answer here. 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58656445/4286568

Comment: @balu I do like what he said, copy+paste, but the problem was still there. and I'm not using UTF-18, instead, I'm using UTF-8. I'm not pro of python and I don't know other problem in my program.

Comment: check what is there in line 239 of the .py file . open in notepad++ and see for any hidden chars that might have crept.

Comment: I just get fine itself without reason...